# Rename a table, if the table is already exists then replace the table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to rename some 100 of tables to another table name. So i have created a query dynamically as (MYSQL),

```
RENAME TABLE table1 TO table 2
```

Now i face a problem that in some cases table 2 is existing already. In this case i want to replace that table 2 with table 1 only and old existing table should not be there.

Please help me on this. I tried using dropping first and rename. But it may cause some problem if i run that script again which will drop the renamed table also.

Comment: What mease "may cause some problem "? Can you specify please?

Comment: yes if i try to rerun the script it will drop the renamed table which i need it..

Comment: You should run your script in a transaction. So that you can make a rollback when you get an error. In other cases you should make a backup of your database and if the result of your script is not ok, then you should restore the db and  rerun the script.